# Boost SOLR relevancy by position of match in multivalued field

Tags: solr

I'm using SOLR 6.2.1, and has the core with multivalued field:

```
<field name="tag_ids" type="ints" required="false"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

It allows to search documents by tag id, with query e.g. `tag_ids:12`. I have tags into this field, sorted by tag relevancy for the document. I want to sort by document tag relevancy.

Example - search query `tag_ids:12`, documents:

```
[
{
   id: 1,
   tag_ids:[1298,43,12,89]
},
{
   id: 2,
   tag_ids:[12,574,1,4356]
},
{
   id: 3,
   tag_ids:[77,12,65]
}
]
```

Wanting to see documents with order 2,3,1 .

**Question**: Is it possible to order by position of match in multi-valued field in Apache SOLR? May be some hacks or plugins?

Comment: Solr isn't looking at the position of a term. In you case all tag_ids got same scores 1

Comment: Perhaps you will need to write your own QueryParserPlugin to make usage of them for your use case.

Comment: While trying to do similar things I noticed that SOLR give an arbitrary "distance" (I forgot how much, 100 or so) between elements in a multi-valued field, so that they are "far away" but not too far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is add the weight information for each tag at index time, and your query would work as is.

To index the weight with each tag, you have several ways:

1. Try with payloads, [here](https://dzone.com/articles/payloads-are-neat-wheres) is a complete example for an older version of Solr, [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/payloads-with-solr.html) is another. You probably would need to modify this samples as Solr apis have changed since then.
2. Use the know hack of adding N times each tag, in your examples that would look like:

   [
   {
   id: 1,
   tag_ids:[1298,1298,1298,1298,43,43,43,12,12,89]
   },
   {
   id: 2,
   tag_ids:[12,12,12,12,574,574,1,1,4356]
   },
   {
   id: 3,
   tag_ids:[77,77,77,77,12,12,12,65,65]
   }]

Comment: [@Persimmonium](http://stackoverflow.com/users/101762/persimmonium) could you also post sample queries for the two possible solutions that you've posted? Thanks in advance.